# Jenkins / Gitlab Multibranch Pipeline not ignoring projects archived in Gitlab

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

We're using Jenkins to orchestrate our builds from GitLab using a Multibranch Pipeline strategy. Recently, something changed somewhere, and now Jenkins is no longer ignoring projects archived in GitLab.

We're using the following stack (not all may be relevant to the problem at hand, and certainly not the complete list of plugins, which would take many pages, if there are other items that I can provide, happy to do so):

- Jenkins:  2.263.3
- Git Plugin 4.5.1
- GitLab Enterprise Edition: 13.7.9-ee
- GitLab API Plugin for Jenkins: 1.0.6
- GitLab Plugin for Jenkins: 1.5.13
- GitLab Branch Source Plugin for Jenkins: 1.5.3

We have our projects organized into groups (with no subgroups) in GitLab, and have used a strategy to archive them when they're no longer needed (instead of deleting them). In Jenkins, we have set up a GitLab Group as an "organization folder", which configures itself to autoscan the GitLab group, searching for projects that have a file named "Jenkinsfile" (configured via project recognizer).

I haven't been able to correlate any recent changes to the behavior I'm seeing, but am still searching. Does anyone have any ideas of where to look to fix this, or is this a known issue?

Thanks!

Comment: similar issue here... were you able to find something ?